# test if first child

Tags: jquery

I'm testing to see if a row in a table is the first child. So far I have:

```
    //the loop works
$('#GridFolderPopup').find('tr').each(function () {

    if ( $(this).is(:first) == true ) //this is the faulty line
    {
         $(this).addClass('GridFolderRow');
    };
});
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may be a solution:

```
$('#GridFolderPopup tr:first').addClass('GridFolderRow');
```

Also reduce the code a lot.

Comment: that's interesting. I'm actually adding this class if the row is not the first child. May be I could add the class to all rows and then remove it from the first row (and last row too if it's the pager row).

Comment: @frienchie - that would be `$('#GridFolderPopup tr:not(:first)').addClass('GridFolderRow');` - [not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Comment: Oh, in this case tou can use the following, it will take every row except the first (gt for Greater Than): `$('#GridFolderPopup tr:gt(0)').addClass('GridFolderRow');`

Answer (score 32):

Try `.is(':first')` instead of `.is(:first)`.

You might be confusing Javascript with Ruby: in Javascript, colon can't be used like this (outside of string).

**edit**
Also, in your case `':first-child'` selector might be more appropriate. See the docs about the difference

http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/
http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Comment: yes, this is a good valid solution: if ( $(this).is(':first-child') == false ). I'm actually testing if first child is false. Thanks.

Comment: @frenchie You'll give better impression to reader, if you use negation (`!`) operator :) `if (!$(this).is(':first-child'))`

Comment: Voted this solution up because this is actually a test.

Answer (score 4):

Simply asking for the first child of the `table`/`tbody` is **much** more efficient than testing every single row in it. The larger the table, the bigger the difference.

Therefore :

- if you want to *"see if a* [given] *row in a table is the first child"*:

  ```
  if ($(a_given_row).prev().length === 0) {
      // no element before this row, so it's the first one.
  }
  ```
- if you want to get the first row of a table:

  ```
  // Directly ask the DOM for the first element child of the table/tbody
  var firstRow = a_given_table.firstChild;
  do {
     firstRow = firstRow.nextSibling;
  } while (firstRow.nodeType !== 1)

  // If you don't need to support IE8-, you can use this single line instead:
  var firstRow = a_given_table.firstChildElement;
  ```

  See performance comparison here: http://jsperf.com/get-first-child-element

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
var allRows=$('#GridFolderPopup').find('tr');
$.each(allRows,function(cntr,value){
            if(cntr==0)
                 $(this).addClass('GridFolderRow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#GridFolderPopup').find('tr').eq(0).addClass('GridFolderRow');
```